# Many - To - Many field changes - Too many api calls

Tags: django, django-models

Using Django, I'm encountering the known issue with the Many-to-Many field. In the post_save_event signal/hook, the value in the Event instance for the many-to-many field: categories does not get updated with the most recent values submitted on the admin form. It always shows the old values.

This is my save hook where I have a parent "Event" and each event has a field for 0 or many categories. However, the instance.categories value is not updated with most recent value.

```py
@receiver(post_save, sender=Event)
def post_save_event(sender, instance, **kwargs):
 success = events_api.create_or_update_event(instance)
```

I'm aware of why this happens. Basically, the many-to-many field needs to save after the parent model because the many-to-many table needs to have the primary key of events.

I did the fix that i found online below. This is the signal that gets sent after the many-to-many table transaction is committed.

This sort of works as a workaround but obviously this means that if the categories change on the event, the api gets called multiple times, even worse the m2m_changed signal seems to fire twice when it happens. So I end up calling the api 3 times for one update.

Any work around/ hook i can use to maybe just do this after a successful form save instead of the post_save event?

```
def category_has_changed(sender, **kwargs):
 logger.error("Inside: Inside category has changed")
 instance = kwargs.pop('instance')
 success = events_api.create_or_update_event(instance)

m2m_changed.connect(category_has_changed, sender=Event.categories.through)
```

Relevant part of the events_api:

```py
def _create_or_update_event(event, mode):
    response = None
    try:
        headers = get_api_headers(event.cms_event_id)

        categories = []
        for cat in event.categories.all():
            categories.append(cat.id)
        # ISSUE: event.categories.all() does not contain the most recent updated array of categories

        # Basic event details.
        body = {
            'cms_event_id': str(event.cms_event_id),
            'categories': categories,
        }
        requests.post(ENDPOINT_CREATE_EVENT, json=body, headers=headers)
```

Models:

```py
class Category(models.Model):
    name_en = models.CharField(
        _('Category name (English)'),
        blank=True, null=True, max_length=200,
        help_text=_('''
        Helpful details (for English language customers) about where the workshop is taking
         place, such as the location inside the store (ex. 2nd floor cafeteria).
        '''))
    name_fr = models.CharField(
        _('Category name (French)'),
        blank=True, null=True, max_length=200,
        help_text=_('''
        Helpful details (for English language customers) about where the workshop is taking
         place, such as the location inside the store (ex. 2nd floor cafeteria).
        '''))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name_en

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name_en',)
        verbose_name_plural = _('Categories')

class Event(Page):
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.ManyToManyField: {'widget': CheckboxSelectMultiple},
    }
    super_manager = models.Manager()

    ...

    categories = models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, null=True, to='Category')
```

Comment: Can you show your Event and Category model and your events_api (the create or update method) so we can understand what you're trying to do? You've walked us through what you think might be a solution but haven't really explained what you're trying to do.

Comment: @dirkgroten I updated the issue with the models and the part of the api for the categories. The api call itself is not a problem, the issue is in the signal that calls the api sends the instance with outdated categories.

I added the signal for when the categories many-to-many table is updated and it calls the api again with the updated categories but this silly to have to call the api twice whenever a foreign key changes. Im just wondering if theres a better hook or signal for this.

Comment: clear now, thanks, good question! You're probably looping through categories when adding them to the event rather than calling `set()` to update them at once. That's why you get multiple calls of m2m_changed. But yes, I wouldn't hook this up to the m2m_changed signal anyway, what happens if later on, a category if removed? This will call m2m_changed for all events, should that create the events again on your api?

Comment: I think I found a way to pass the value from the form. I will update with a solution

Answer (score 0):

I was able to modify my save_model in my modelAdmin like so

```
class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    obj.new_categories = form.cleaned_data.get('categories')
    obj.save()

    super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Then in signals.py i have it as part of the instance:

instance.new_category